# why math.RoundToEven() working like this?

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang but i found a strange behavior (and correct me if i am wrong)
The function math.RoundToEven() supposed to return a rounded even number but unexpectedly it returns odd number

I am running Golang 1.21.6 on ubuntu machine
I have reported the issue on Golang github issues,but the answer was strange!!
[the issue on github](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/65179)

Any idea what is the problem
Do u think this is a bug!!!!!!?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(math.RoundToEven(17.1))
      //answer supposed to be 18 but it returned 17!!!
}
```

Comment: The function uses the even number as a tie breaker.  There is no tie to break with 17.1.

Comment: A tie only happens at or really close to x.5: https://go.dev/play/p/rYRYr_m1zNw

Comment: `RoundToEven` is not supposed to return an even number, even though the name may imply that. When you want to know what a function does you must read the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/math#RoundToEven). The function name is simply a mnemonic symbol and may mislead you.

Comment: you are right the name of the function confused me

Comment: "The function math.RoundToEven() supposed to return a rounded even number" Why do you think that? A function does what it's documentation says it does. Always, literally _always_ read the documentation including the general package doc.

Answer (score 3):

`RoundToEven` returns the nearest integer, rounding ties to even (a tie is essentially exactly half way between two whole numbers, so .5). Which is a confusing statement, so an example to demonstrate:

- 11.4 rounds to 11.0
- 11.5 rounds to 12.0
- 11.6 rounds to 12.0
- 12.4 rounds to 12.0
- 12.5 rounds to 12.0
- 12.6 rounds to 13.0

Comment: I don't know if go's math library has a `round` function, but this literally sounds no different than regular rounding.

Comment: @Shmack [`Round`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Round) rounds half values away from zero (i.e., "round up").

Comment: @Shmack I guess that depends what "regular" rounding means to you. :)  Go does have a "Round" function, which rounds away from zero.  i.e. +n.5 will round to n+1 and -n.5 will round to n-1.  RoundToEven is what is sometimes called "bankers rounding", so called because it is intended to average away "losses" or "gains" accumulated when consistently rounding away from zero.

Comment: @Deltics, I guess ignorance is, still, bliss.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that actually rounds to even numbers only, use the following:

```golang
func roundToEven(f float64) float64 {
    return math.Round(f/2) * 2
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/cwSMCt6KxU6)